# Populating dropdown from SQL Server with ajax in C# and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

It seem that debugger doesnt enter at all at the success function. The dropdown im trying to populate is part of a modal in /Dokument/Dokument route when i press a button i get a modal with some fields. One of the fields is a dropdown which has to get values from Tipi table. In the dropdown I see nothing not even the message

Route config

```
namespace Archieve1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

AJAX script

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/NgarkoDokumentController/GetTipi",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                var s = '<option value="-1">Selektoni Tipin</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    s += '<option value="' + data[i].Id_Tipi + '">' + data[i].Emri_llojit + '</option>';
                }
                $("#tipiDropdown").html(s);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller method

```
 using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Archieve1.Controllers
{
    public class NgarkoDokumentController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Dokument()
        {
             return View();
        }
        // GET: NgarkoDokument

            
        public ActionResult GetTipi()
        {
            Test_kristiEntities db = new Test_kristiEntities();
            return Json(db.Tipi.Select(x => new
            {
                Id_Tipi = x.Id_Tipi,
                Emri_llojit = x.Emri_llojit
            }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            // return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model I built with some tables

```
namespace Archieve1.Models
{
    public class NgarkoDokument
    {
        public Dokumenti Dokumenti { get; set; }
        public Fusha_Indeksimit FushaIndeksimit { get; set; }
        public Vendndodhja_Fizike Vendndodhja_fizike { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Tipi> Tipi { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

And here is the html

```
@model Archieve1.Models.NgarkoDokument
    <select title="Lloji i dokumentit" name="lloji" class="form-control col-md-3 box" id="tipiDropdown"> </select>
```

Comment: Well, start debugging. First, check if `/NgarkoDokumentController/GetTipi` is actually returning what you're expecting. The easiest way to check this is to request the URL using your browser. Second, add `console.log(data);` to your `success` callback function to see if your AJAX request is receiving the data correctly.

Comment: I started debugging, it doesnt enter at all at success function and I get this error ::44365/NgarkoDokumentController/GetTipi?{}:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () . What can I do now any suggestion?

Comment: That tells us that the route `/NgarkoDokumentController/GetTipi` could not be resolved. If you put a breakpoint in `GetTipi()`, it will probably never be hit either? Can you add more details about the controller method, namely the controller itself and your route config?

Comment: Yes it doesnt enter at all

Comment: Okay so the route is /Dokument/Dokument
controller name is NgarkoDokumentController
model name is NgarkoDokument
and the function name is GetTipi
The form im building is part of a modal that opens when i click on a button in /Dokument/Dokument
In the modal I have a dropdown that im trying to populate with ajax

Comment: Shouldn't the URL you're performing the AJAX request on be `/Dokument/GetTipi`, then?

Comment: Just changed it buit I still get same error

Comment: Can you update your post to include the full controller and RouteConfig?

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: I'm still not seeing the `RouteConfig`. The route configuration is essential to debugging issues regarding routing. Routes like `/Dokument/Dokument` and `/NgarkoDokumentController/GetTipi` could never work if you have no route configuration.

Comment: It seems the path is /Dokument/Dokument/GetTipi now im getting the message Selekto Tipin but the values im getting are undefined. I just added the routeconfig.cs

Comment: I'm sorry, but when you say "im getting the message Selekto Tipin", I have no idea what you mean. I do not know the context of your application, nor the language it's using. Regardless, try `/NgarkoDokument/GetTipi`. Earlier you said the page is accessed on `/Dokument/Dokument`, but that cannot be true, considering your current route config would never allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default route of ASP.NET MVC 5 `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, and the `/{id}` part is optional.

`{controller}` refers to the class name of your C# controller, but it removes the word `Controller` at the end. In your example, the controller name would be `NgarkoDokument`.

`{action}` refers to the method name of your action. In your example, `GetTipi`.

So the route becomes `/NgarkoDokument/GetTipi`.

Here's the relevant documentation:

- ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs
- Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/